# Can an activity within pipeline have source dataset residing in different data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Generally the source dataset is present in the same data factory. Is it possible that an activity refers to an input data set which actually resides in a different data factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it's not - different data factories do not know about each other's existence, which means that (among other things) they can't refer to each other's datasets.

Your best option is to have all of your datasets reside in the same data factory. If that's not possible, you can create a data source in data factory #2 marked as "external" that references a dataset produced by data factory #1. The official documentation has more information about this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-create-datasets/